# AngularJS Factory : JSon and Authorization

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a problem with my AngularJS factory. Actually, I have to make a request which includes a JSon variable, and it has an Authorization header.

It looks like this :

```
createEvent:function(event){
    return $http.get(url, {
        headers: { 'Authorization' : token }
    })
}
```

The event variable is a JSon object, and I want to get it in the $http.get function as I have a Validator in the backend which tests this json file.
Is there any way for me to pass this variable here ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks strange that you use the 'GET' method to send data.

```
createEvent:function(event){
  return $http.post(url, {
      headers: { 'Authorization' : token },
      data : event
  })
}
```

seems better.

Also check that your content type is correctly set.

Comment: Yeah, the data could only be recognized with the post type of call. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can pass event json as data.

```
createEvent:function(event){
    return $http.get(url, {
        headers: { 'Authorization' : token },
        data : event
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm on it. I'm looking in my Scala backend. Apparently my request.body.asJson.map{...}.getOrElse(badRequest("invalidJSON")) executes the badRequest, so I have to see what I do have to change

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send the data using [`params`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) object when using `GET` http method. Other thing is if you are sending JSON string you need to [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it.

```
...
$http.get(url, {
    headers: {'Authorization': token},
    params: event // or "JSON.parse(event)" if event is json string
});
```